# How to change chars between 2 strings?

Tags: java, string, char

I want to change a char in a String with another in second String, the distance is 3.

For example:
String s1:abc,
String s2:abcdef->s2 will be abadef then -> abadeb.

If it is possible all chars from first String should goes to second s2. I have to mention that upperCase letters from the first should be lowerCase, and only letters will be taken from the first String. I know Strings are immutable

```
public static void Encrypt(String s1, String s2) {
        s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
        StringBuilder finalS2 = new StringBuilder();
        finalS2.append(s2);

        for (int i = 0; i < finalS2.length(); i++) {

            if (s1.charAt(i) >= 'a' && s1.charAt(i) <= 'z') {

                finalS2.setCharAt(i + 2, s1.charAt(0));

                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(finalS2);
    }
```

I think in my method, which I don't think is a good idea, I should place another for loop for s1 and a break somewhere. I tried many methods, with charArray, etc. but didn't managed.

Comment: Can you better explain what do you need? The question is not clear (for me).

Comment: Let's say i have 2 strings  that are user input. First String is:"car" and the second is "restaurant" i want to get 'c' on 3 position so it will be:"rectaurant" then 'a' on the 6 position so it will be "rectaarant"  and 'r' on 9 if it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly this should work. everyX in your example would be 3

```
public static String encrypt(String s1, String s2, int everyX) {
    //Start with S2
    StringBuilder finalS2 = new StringBuilder(s2);
    s1 = s1.toLowerCase();

    int indexInS1 = 0;
    //Whilst there are characters in S2 and S1 left to iterate over
    for (int placeInS2 = 0; placeInS2 < finalS2.length() && indexInS1 < s1.length(); placeInS2++) {
         //Has there been everyX places encountered and the character in S1 is alphanumeric
        if ((placeInS2 + 1) % everyX == 0) {
            if (Character.isAlphabetic(s1.charAt(indexInS1)) {
                finalS2.setCharAt(placeInS2, s1.charAt(indexInS1));
            }
            indexInS1++;
        }
    }

    return finalS2.toString();
}
```

Comment: You understood well man,thanks,I tested a few times,and last char from s1 doen't go to the s2.But i think i will find from here a way.Thanks

Comment: I had (s1.length() - 1) which I've changed. I've also removed the count variable

Comment: It is working,thanks,i marked the answer.Nice feedback even for easy question :)

Answer (score 2):

So you want to take the original text of `s2` and replace every third character with characters from `s1`:

```
s1: abc
    ││└───── ignored
    │└───┐
    └─┐  │
s2: abcdef
```

Best way to do incremental single-char replacements like that is to get the `char[]` of the original string (`s2`), replace the appropriate characters, then build the resultant string from that.

```
public static String encrypt(String s1, String s2) {
    char[] buf = s2.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0, j = 2; i < s1.length() && j < buf.length; i++, j += 3) {
        buf[j] = Character.toLowerCase(s1.charAt(i));
    }
    return new String(buf);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(encrypt("abc", "abcdef"));
```

*Output*

```
abadeb
```

If you want the code to handle characters from the Unicode supplemental planes, e.g. emojis, then you need to work with code points.

You also mentioned that you only want letters from `s1`, so we'll add that to the next version *(`codePoints()` requires Java 9+)*.

```
public static String encrypt(String s1, String s2) {
    int[] c1 = s1.codePoints().toArray();
    int[] c2 = s2.codePoints().toArray();
    for (int i = 0, j = 2; i < c1.length && j < c2.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c1[i])) {
            c2[j] = Character.toLowerCase(c1[i]);
            j += 3;
        }
    }
    return new String(c2, 0, c2.length);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(encrypt("abc", "abcdef"));
System.out.println(encrypt("ace", "acegikm"));
```

*Output*

```
abadeb
aaecgekm
```

As you can see, emoji characters in `s1` are skipped, since they are not "letters", and emojis in `s2` are correctly replaced. Even though  takes up 2 `char` positions in `s2`, it is correct replaced by `c`, a single `char` value.

Comment: I didn't think so far to emoji,but I tested your solution and it's working.Your solution is good and easy to understand.Thank you for your time.

Comment: Off topic question: How did you manage to draw the lines in the first code block?

Comment: @user7 Web search for [`unicode box drawing`](https://www.google.com/search?q=unicode+box+drawing), select the [`Box-drawing character - Wikipedia`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) link, select/scroll to the [`Unicode`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character#Unicode) section, then **copy/paste** the relevant characters.

Comment: You could have just specified the last link to save time ;)

Comment: Sure. Agreed. But I would (and expect others too) look around the (wiki) page and learn that it can be used to draw any such unicode point. Curiosity to learn the general principles and extend it and apply in the future :)

Comment: @user7 I wasn't referring to people looking around the Wikipedia page, I was referring to people ***starting with a web search***, when they need to find out how to do stuff.